How to implement multiple pages into iframe using srcdoc
I'm working on a website editor, and one of the roadblocks I'm running into is how to implement multiple pages
I'm currently taking the user provided HTML, CSS, and JS, and then jamming it all into a single iframe using srcdoc (which already isn't very practical), however this won't work with implementing multiple pages, so I'm trying to find solutions or alternatives.
I want to make it work the same way an actual website would function, however I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.
Currently I'm generating a preview like so:


const html = document.querySelector("textarea#html")
const css = document.querySelector("textarea#css")
const js = document.querySelector("textarea#js")

const runButton = document.querySelector("button#run")

const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe")

runButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let generatedHTML = `${html.value}
    <style>${css.value}<\/style>
    <script>${js.value}<\/script>`
  iframe.srcdoc = generatedHTML
})
textarea, button, iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  height: 80px;
}
<textarea id="html" placeholder="html"><h1>Hello</h1> world!</textarea>
<textarea id="css" placeholder="css">h1 {color: blue;}</textarea>
<textarea id="js" placeholder="js">// No js for this demo, it's there though!</textarea>
<button id="run">run</button>
<iframe></iframe>



(Link to the live project: https://luckivibes.codeberg.page/webedit/ )

Are you trying to make your own custom CMS? The question isn't very clear, and it's not obvious what you're doing with iframes here or why. (iframe is pretty legacy, a bit clunky, and usually considered a last resort for most purposes)

@ADyson Not quite, more attempting to create an editing interface, somewhat like codepen, not necessarily a place to host it. As for my unclear question, would you have any suggestions as to what to change? I've never been good at writing questions on here.
(As for iframe being legacy, I'm mostly just unsure what else to use for my use case)

Well I don't think we really understand the use case properly, for one thing. [ask] has general guidance on asking a good question, and the [mre] article explains how to post code which reproduces your specific issue / explains your scenario without any redundant content. At the very least we need to see what you're currently doing. (And links to your project aren't acceptable: What topics can I ask about here? is very clear that any code needed to understand the problem must be within your question (since other links can change or die over time))

@ADyson Alrighty, I'll try to fix my question, thank you very much for the help!

Thanks for the link to the live-running project. So you're trying to reproduce codepen? Anything different (feature-wise) in what you're doing than what that site, or JSFiddle etc, or already provide?

From what I can see (just from examining the page source), in terms of layout CodePen just puts all the different part of the page (e.g. JS area, HTML area, CSS area) into <div> elements, aside from the actual running demo of the code, which seems to be in an iframe. JSFiddle seems to be similar. So that would seem to be a reasonable approach. It looks like you've done something like that in your app too. So what exactly is the problem you're having? Is something not working the way you want it to?

@ADyson
For your first comment: In a way, yes, however I'm trying to go far past just a single page, and allow for the creation of entire websites entirely from the browser
As for the problem, as I stated above, I'm wanting to expand past just a single page, and allow for the preview to be navigated like a regular website (I'm not entirely too sure how I can explain that more clearly in my question)

Ok. So you want hyperlinks and form submissions to work in a realistic way? There are sandbox sites which let you do that I think, but they tend to be a lot more sophisticated and likely have a sandbox webserver sitting behind them, or at least something that emulates it - I'm thinking of sites like Stackblitz

@ADyson Yep, pretty much! And I'll have to look into how they implement it, I'm not really able to do any hosting/server-side stuff at the moment, and I'm generally trying to keep offline functionality, so I'm trying to avoid it, but it is an option I've considered

I don't really know how you'd avoid it, aside from perhaps somehow emulating an entire webserver environment within client-side JS. If you want to click links and submit forms, that normally generates HTTP requests. And those requests need to have somewhere to go, if you expect there to be a response and for something else to be displayed in its place. Of course there are things like SPAs which deliberately aim to have dynamic content within a single page, without navigating. But in your case you've no control over what code the user is going to write.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can create rich text editors for

HTML
CSS
Javascript

and maybe other controllers, such as checkbox lists of well-known libraries that could be automatically added to the preview (like jquery, to mention an ancient example).
Have a folder for all pages to be previewed and have a name for this folder. Inside this folder have an html, a css a js file as well as a settings file and implement the saving of these files as well as the parsing of these files together into a web-page. That is, add the JS and CSS part as <script> and <style> tags into the <head> of the page and the HTML structure into the <body> and of course whatever additional controllers you have should be proogrammed as you see it fit.
Finally, in order to view a preview, you can either use an iframe or do window.open("the/url/here", "_blank")

This isn't really what I'm looking for, I want to dynamically show the preview on the fly, and accessing files saved to the user's filesystem is... complicated if not impossible depending on what you want to do

@Vixey you could save your changes into a user's session as well. To be quite honest you will likely reach the conclusion that you need to save the changes in files so they will be reusable, but you will also have quick saves into the session of the user to not do the heavilifting of file saves upon each saves. My answer simplifies this question and suggested that you should first implement this with file saves. Later on you can add save caches.
